# using javascript in php for php session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The Code is:

```
<?php include 'connection.php';
if($logged_in=='yes')
{
    echo "hell yea!"; //just for test and it works
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("test 1 2 3"); //works too.
    $("#form1").hide(); //to hide login form, but doesn't work
    </script> 
    <?php
}
?>
```

I think question is quite clear. What is the reason? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: The session events are work fine by connection.php. No problem logging in or logout etc.**

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="form1" name="form1" >
  <label for="username"></label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="textbox"/>
  <label for="password"></label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="textbox"/>
  <span  id="submit" class="submit">Log in</span>
</div>
<div>
<span id="logged_in" class="logged_in">Hello user etc.</span> //normally it is hidden from css.
</div>
```

and here is how I login:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"login.php",
data: '{"username":"'+$("#username").val()+'","password":"'+$("#password").val()+'"}',
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
    if(data.ok=="done!"){
        $("#form1").hide();
        $("#giris").show();
        $("#giris").html('Hello '+data.name+' '+data.lastname+' <a href="my_account.php">My Account</a>');                      
                    }
    else if(data.ok=="No such user!")                       
        alert("No such user");                                  
    else                        
    alert(data.ok); //activation required                                               
                }               
});
});
```

EDIT: `alert()` line. HTML code added. Jquery part is added. And this forum tells me my post is mostly code so I think I have type something here. And I think I just did.

Comment: check error in Console .

Comment: @Haseeb I already did. And nothing. no error. Just form1 is coming back.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to tell what the problem is… but you shouldn't generate JavaScript to hide the login form, you should just not output the HTML for the login form at all when the user is logged in.

Comment: Please paste the code of html form

Comment: Your code is right. Please make sure that jQuery working in your page by giving alert($);

Comment: @Quentin you can't see the account page until log in. So session things work good. I just can't hide the login form.

Comment: Javascript runs on client side, so it won't work because your page is not ready and the code already has been executed.

Comment: @RohitBatham alert worked, thanks but why the other doesn't?

Comment: @WhoCares — That doesn't have anything to do with the two points I made.

Comment: @Jai — The JavaScript running on the client side isn't a problem here. It would only be an issue if the OP was trying to use JS to stop PHP sending the login form at all, instead of just hiding it. (Hiding it with JS is, as I pointed out, a bad approach to the problem, but not one that can't work)

Comment: Don't just show us the HTML code without context, show us how it relates to the PHP code.

Comment: Have you looked at your JavaScript error console? What does it say?

Comment: @Quentin I use ajax to login. anyway, ok wait. I think I going to paste everything. and nothing in console. no error.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/), you have label elements, but they are useless. They need text inside them and either a `for` attribute or to be wrapped around the inputs. You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/).

Comment: @Quentin I know it is useless, but are they the reason of why hide command is not working? I think they aren't. I can fix the html part later. For now, I need this issue fixed. Thanks

Comment: @WhoCares — No, if they were I'd have given an answer.

Comment: @WhoCares — Your Ajax handlers expect to be dealing in JSON, they have nothing to do with the script element you are outputting if the user is logged in.

Comment: And don't try to hand craft JSON by smashing together strings. What if a user's password contained a `"`? Use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @Quentin I handled them in the registration form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Hope it will work.

```
<?php include 'connection.php';
if($logged_in=='yes')
{
    echo "hell yea!"; //just for test and it works
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){$("#form1").hide(); });
    </script> 
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But how? can you tell me the difference?

Comment: in your code, it executed before loading all the page elements. That is it tried to hide an element with id form 1 which wasn't loaded yet and failed. In the code that I pasted, that javascript hide() will be executed only after the pageload. That is after all the elements are loaded. And so it hides the form. Hope you understood. :)

Comment: Ah ok, I see, you say you cannot `i++;` before `int i=0;` salut to `C++` :)

Answer (score -1):

where dou you get tehe value of the session????

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['logged_in']='yes';
?>
```

then

```
<?php include 'connection.php';
//////if($logged_in=='yes')
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']=='yes')
{
    echo "hell yea!"; //just for test and it works
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form1").hide(); //to hide login form, but doesn't work
    </script> 
    <?php
}
?>
```

check this link:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

I hope this help you men!

Comment: from the connection.php, session things are working fine. I just can't hide the form1.

Comment: the "hell yea!" is printed?

Comment: can you copy the complete code of your page???

Comment: only copy and paste it